# Application is not loading in simulator using Eclipse

Tags: deployment, blackberry, build

I am able to build a application what I have , however when
I check in simulator there is no application icon available using  Eclipse, i have checked carefully there are no errors.

When I run same application in JDE ,application icon  is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking if your project is activated for blackberry...or there may be no main method in your appliaction..

Answer (score 1):

Did your try to start the simulator and manually add the cod file via "File" -> "Load COD File". Sometimes the app get loaded into the download directory on your simulator/device.